# Typescript - Using an abstract class to simple share a function

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript, I have 2 functions, within them they have the exact same function code. Therefore I decided to take that common function out into its own file.

However I've done it like below - and wonder should I instead be creating an abstract class which has that function (others will go in there soon). Or is it just as `nice` to keep it as I've done at the moment.

So file 1:

```
import { sharedFunction } from "../common/actions";

export async function onTrigger(context: Context, documents: Resource[] | null): Promise<void> {
   sharedFunction(aParamFile1, bParamFile1)
}
```

file 2:

```
import { sharedFunction } from "../common/actions";

export async function onTrigger(context: Context, documents: Resource[] | null): Promise<void> {
   sharedFunction(aParamFile2, bParamFile2)
}
```

actions file with shared function:

```
export async function sharedFunction(input1: someType, input2: someType){
   //Do something
}}
```

The reason I wonder if it should be an abstract class is say I have several functions I want to use in `file1` or `file2` I'd need to list them all in the `import` lines at the top. Is that seen as `untidy` design or is it acceptable? 
I was wondering whether it could be avoided so instead do `myAbstractClass.sharedFunction`?

But on the other hand I don't see how that `onTrigger` function can extend that abstract class being a function.

Any ideas/advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of introducing an artificial namespace class (which you don't really need), you can just change your import to:

```
import * as shared from '../common/actions';
```

This will import everything from that module. Then prefix the functions thus imported with `shared.`.

Comment: Thanks - that looks useful. So avoid abstract functions you think as I'm not really creating a new object of sorts?

Comment: @userMod2: "Abstract function"? If you need a class, then write one. But if you just need a container for a bunch of functions (a namespace), you don't need a class: you already have the module.

Comment: Sorry - meant to say abstract class. But what you saying makes sense. Thanks